# An example of a normal spaces $X,Y$ such that $X\times Y$ is not normal.

Tags: general-topology

Apparently in a topological space, the property of being normal (can separate closed sets) is not productive.

What is an example of such a space? In other words, normal spaces $X$ and $Y$ such that $X\times Y$ is not normal.

Comment: See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/361247/the-product-space-of-sorgenfrey-line-is-not-normal).

Comment: Perfect. Thanks!